# How to change sysprint value in Enterprise Guide 7.1

Tags: sas

how could I change sysprint option value in Enterprise Guide 7.1? 
I've done it on a SAS 9.4 enviroment and it was done successfully. Sadly, doing that in a program on Enterprise Guide didn't have the same result.

Comment: What was the code used ? Log messages ? Connected to local host or a server ?

Comment: Local host. The code used was options sysprint = "printer-name"; Got an error about the setting on sysprint will be ignored.